# Push parts of a project using GIT

Tags: git, azure, asp.net-core

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.git
docs
src
  proj.web
  proj.api
test
  proj.web.test
  proj.api.test
```

I am using the following to push everything to Github:

```
git add -a
git commit . -m "Commit"  
git push -u origin master
```

This works but I also need to push individual projects to Azure using git.

But in that case I need to push only proj.web and proj.api to 2 different git urls and not everything to one url.

How should I do this?

**Update**

After configuring continuous deployment in Azure I got the Deployment Scripts from Kudu which contains the following:

```
:: 1. Restore nuget packages
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet restore
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Build and publish
call :ExecuteCmd dotnet publish "src\proj.web\proj.web.csproj" --output "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" --configuration Release
```

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

```
:: 3. KuduSync
call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" -t     "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
```

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

When I Sync in Azure I get the following error:

```
Most Recent Commit
GitHub
Failed
10:35 PM
```

With the error:

Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET Core Web Application deployment.
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet restore
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\59.60125.2666\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

I am working with ASP.NET Core 1.1 using csproj file in Visual Studio Code.

I do not have a project.json ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong here but I am guessing that you are referring to [Continuous Deployment to an Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment)?

If so, the problem you are describing is basically that you want to keep multiple App Services in the same repo? The front end and back end part of the same application for instance. If that is the case then you can change how Continuous Deployment to each App Service looks for a web project in the repo when it is trying to deploy it.

Go to the Kudu interface for your App Service. It can be found at `https://{your-website-name-goes-here}.scm.azurewebsites.net`. In the menu you can find `Tools > Download Deployment Script`. Open the zip and you have 2 files: `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd`. Open `deploy.cmd`. Find the section that looks like this:

```
:: 2. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Company.SolutionName\Company.Solution.ProjectName\Company.Solution.ProjectName.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Company.SolutionName\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
) ELSE (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Company.SolutionName\Company.Solution.ProjectName\Company.Solution.ProjectName.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Company.SolutionName\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
)
```

Now go ahead and for each App Service just change `Company.SolutionName\Company.Solution.ProjectName\Company.Solution.ProjectName.csproj` to the path of the web project you want to deploy to that specific App Service.

When you are done, add the `.deploy` and `deploy.cmd` to the root of your repo (same level as `.git`). When you push to your repo now each App Service will build only the csproj that you have specified in each custom deployment script.

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: @yoape I activated continuous deployment in Azure and went to Kudu url but when I tried to download the scripts I got the message {"Message":"Operation only supported if not using a custom deployment script"} ... In Azure all I did was to activate the continuous deployment and select the Github repository. What am I missing?

Comment: @MiguelMoura, do you have a ``.deploy`` file in your repo already perhaps? You can also check with KUDU by going to ``Debug console > CMD``, under ``D:\home\site\repository`` you should see what is pulled down from the repo. If you can't get that to work, you can use this gist https://gist.github.com/FredrikGoransson/bf859ea23c6fe4b4cb578dc12e83e948 and just modify the filenames and paths.

Comment: I was able Sync but the application does not build ... I just updated my question with extra information.

Comment: I just created a new App Service and a clean repo with a .NET core web in. Downloaded the deployment script and added that as ``.deploy`` and ``deploy.cmd`` to the repo. Deployed again. Added another .NET core web to the repo, watched the redeployment. It all worked fine. Perhaps there is some snafu in your repo or code? I put my test repo public: https://github.com/FredrikGoransson/Azure.NETCore.KUDU.Deploy, you can fork that and try to deploy with it, it should (hopefully) work for you as well.

Comment: Btw, if you go in to KUDU and go to Debug Console > CMD and then navigate to ``D:\home\site\repository\src\proj.web``, is the ``proj.web.csproj`` as your deployment script expects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use branches for that if you need to keep those in the same repo, else you can use 2 repos.